# Raycasting and 2d arrays not working as expected with Rubik's Cube in Unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I hope this is a fine question, but I am currently working on a Rubik's Cube in Unity. I have a 3d array of a custom MonoBehaviour, `Cubie`, which each contains a 1d array of `Face` objects. I then have this code in the `Start()` method to create 2d arrays of Faces to map the changes to the cube (I am certain this isn't the most efficient way of doing things, but this is for a project that is meant to involve matrix transformations):

```
for (int i = 0; i < cube.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cube.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < cube.GetLength(2); k++)
                {
                    cube[i, j, k] = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(i, j, k), Quaternion.identity, transform);

                    Cubie cubie = cube[i, j, k];
                    Face[] faces = cubie.GetFaces();
                    foreach (Face face in faces)
                    {
                        if (face.GetFaceType() == FaceType.Up) upFace[j, k] = face;
                        if (face.GetFaceType() == FaceType.Down) downFace[j, k] = face;
                        if (face.GetFaceType() == FaceType.Right) rightFace[j, k] = face;
                        if (face.GetFaceType() == FaceType.Left) leftFace[j, k] = face;
                        if (face.GetFaceType() == FaceType.Front) frontFace[j, k] = face;
                        if (face.GetFaceType() == FaceType.Back) backFace[j, k] = face;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have a set of UI Panels that acts as a 2d representation of the cube, and they show up like this:
[image: Rubik's Cube 2D Map]

This works as intended, so I assumed that the 2d arrays were working perfectly fine. However, once I started trying to raycast to get the side that was clicked, it only works on the cubies attached to the right side. Based on the fact that when I changed the above code it changed which side of the cube worked  with the raycasts, I assume the issue is with that code, not anything to do with the raycasts themselves, but I can give you that code if needed.

Comment: Just as a follow-up, I've figured out where I went wrong, but haven't yet found a way to solve it. I need to use `i`, `j`, and `k` on each side depending on the side. Currently I have 3 of the 6 faces working as intended, but I'm a little stumped on the rest.

Comment: I used an excel sheet to visualize which variables needed to be used where, and it mostly works. I think the rest of the bugs are unrelated though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone is curious, here is my solution to my issue:

As I mentioned in comments, I was going about it very wrong, so when I figured out that I needed to change around which faces made use of which variables, I managed to get further. After a bit of playing around, I made an excel spreadsheet to help me visualize what I would use to map the faces correctly.
[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

This let me then apply the correct mapping in the for loops, and eventually I ended up with something that worked as intended. At first, I plugged in the variables in the wrong order, which ended up causing a couple of other bugs, but I was able to fix that by just switching around the order, and voila, I have things working properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Instantiate function, you can get object like this clone(....).

Instantiate function creates objects not Gameobject, so in order to use prefab you add 'as Gameobject' to the end of Instantiate function like this.

```
cube[i, j, k] = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(i, j, k), Quaternion.identity, transform) as GameObject;
```

And, you have to use physicsRaycast for raycast operation.
I hope my answer will be for your question.

Comment: The array `cube` is not an array of GameObjects, but an array of a custom MonoBehaviour `Cubie`, so I'm fairly certain casting is not necessary. I've debugged to the point where I can narrow down the problem to something to do with the for loop logic in the code above, but I can't seem to figure out how to iterate over the lists to set up the faces properly. I hope this is a slightly better explanation than the one I gave in the question.

Comment: Ah, I see, In my thought, cubies attached to the right side is set right for getting raycast, but others are not set for getting raycast. Maybe, if the faces of cube is turned over, the faces can't get ray from mouse.  As you can see, raycast requires collision, so you'd better check the other face's placement.